# Xcode / Define custom pre selected font

Tags: xcode

If I put a Label, the pre-selected font always is: "System 17"

Is it possible to define a pre-selected font for the interface builder? F.e Avenir Next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Your easiest choice is to make one label whose font is AvenirNext and then copy and paste it to make your other labels.

Comment: too bad... really really too bad... it's so annoying... but thank you for the quick answer